# Obsidian formats code in a wierd way when in Read-Mode

Tags: obsidian

I am fairly new to Obsidian and have run into an issue that I can't resolve:
When in Edit-Mode the code I put into my note gets looks normal and how I formatted it to look like, but as soon as I switch into Read-Mode, the formatting is all over the place.
(See picture below: left is edit-mode and right is read-mode) [image: left is edit-mode and right is read-mode]

This only happens in this instance (so far), all my other code blocks get displayed fine. It is react code marked with JFX.

I have tried importing the code again and reformatting it by hand but get the same result.
Also I have searched for code-format plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:
It was the Theme I had selected (Everforest) that messed the code-formatting up.